# Distance function for sas 9.2

Tags: sas, sas-iml

In SAS 9.3 we can easily calculate the Euclidean distance matrix between lat, lon  by using function `distance`

```
proc iml;
n=5; 
seed=123456789;
    lat= J(n,1,0); lon= J(n,1,0);
    i = 1;  do while (i <= n); 
    lat[i] = uniform(seed);                                                                                                  
    lon[i] = uniform(seed);                                                                                                  
     i = i + 1;  end;
mat=lat||lon;
dist=distance(mat); 
run;
quit;
```

I can't find this function in SAS 9.2
How can I do it in 9.2 ?

Thank you.

Comment: BTW, try
mat = J(n,2);
call randseed(seed);
call randgen(mat, "Uniform");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rick Wicklin answers this question in a [blog post](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/03/27/compute-distance/), in which he introduces the `distance` function, but also tells you how to do it two other ways.

- PROC DISTANCE (not an IML procedure, but produces a matrix-like dataset you could easily load into IML)
- Write your own module.  You need to create a `pairwisedist()` module that would define how to compute euclidian distance for a matrix.  Essentially you determine the difference between all combinations of the rows in the matrix.  Then sum the squares of the differences and take the square root.

An example of `PROC DISTANCE`:

```
proc iml;
n=5; 
seed=123456789;
    lat= J(n,1,0); lon= J(n,1,0);
    i = 1;  do while (i <= n); 
    lat[i] = uniform(seed);                                                                                                  
    lon[i] = uniform(seed);                                                                                                  
     i = i + 1;  end;


  mat=lat||lon;
  create matdata from mat [colname={'x1' 'x2' 'x3' 'x4' 'x5'}];
    append from mat;
  close matdata;
  quit;

proc distance data=matdata out=dist method=Euclid nostd;
  var interval(x1 x2);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for help, I prefer using Wicklin's function in proc iml; I posted my answer for iml using your helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Joe, I can use the answer of Rick Wicklin in `proc iml` as :

```
proc iml;
n=5; 
seed=123456789;
    lat= J(n,1,0); lon= J(n,1,0);
    i = 1;  do while (i <= n); 
    lat[i] = uniform(seed);                                                                                                  
    lon[i] = uniform(seed);                                                                                                  
     i = i + 1;  end;
mat=lat||lon;

start PairwiseDist(x, y);
if ncol(x)^=ncol(y) then return (.); /* Error */
p = nrow(x); q = nrow(y);
idx = T(repeat(1:p, q)); /* index matrix for x */
jdx = shape(repeat(1:q, p), p); /* index matrix for y */
diff = abs(X[idx,] - Y[jdx,]);
return( shape( sqrt(diff[,##]), p ) );
finish;
start EuclideanDistance(x); /* in place of 12.1 DISTANCE function */
y=x;
return( PairwiseDist(x,y) );
finish;
distance=EuclideanDistance(mat);
print distance;

run;
quit;
```

Thank you Joe and thaks to Rick Wicklin.